# UrlRewriting.net rewrite .htm to extensionless, but ignore umbraco directories

Tags: regex, umbraco, urlrewriting.net

I need to redirect all of the legacy `.htm` urls for my website to extensionless urls, so:

```
http://www.website.com/page.htm  -->  http://www.website.com/page
```

I created the following rule in config/UrlRewriting.config, which fixed the above issue, but created an issue where all of the backoffice paths are returning 404:

```
<add name="HtmToExtensionless"
     redirect="Domain"
     ignoreCase="true" 
     rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite"
     virtualUrl="http://www.website.com/(.*)(\.htm)"
     redirectMode="Permanent"
     destinationUrl="http://www.website.com/$1" />
```

So requests like these are returning 404:

```
http://www.website.com/umbraco/views/components/application/umb-navigationl?umb__rnd=7.4.2.1536555776
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is with my regex, but I'm not sure. Anyone care to advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was being a dufus.  Umbraco actually requests resources that have `.html` extensions, and my regex was grabbing those and stripping the `.htm` from them.  Just had to check for the beginning and end of the string, and now we're golden:

```
<add name="HtmToExtensionless"
     redirect="Domain"
     ignoreCase="true" 
     rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite"
     virtualUrl="^http://www.website.com/(.*)(\.htm)$"
     redirectMode="Permanent"
     destinationUrl="http://www.website.com/$1" />
```